# Running espec task from iex

Tags: elixir

For a file watcher project, I'd like to run [espec](https://github.com/antonmi/espec) from `iex`.

I figured out that I can do

```
Mix.Task.run "espec", [file_path]
```

That only works once. I gotten around to reset the state via

```
Mix.Task.reenable "espec"
```

And that seemed to work. But then I ran in something strange. Say I have `file1_spec.exs` and `file2_spec.exs`. Whichever I run first will always be run in the shell.

```
Mix.Task.reenable "espec"
Mix.Task.run "espec", ["file1_spec.exs"]
# output of file1_spec.exs
Mix.Task.reenable "espec"
Mix.Task.run "espec", ["file2_spec.exs"]
# still output of file1_spec.exs
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried something like reloading the project, as [described here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elixir-lang-talk/uU8K2NJAE70/vs-b2GL1VscJ)? I think the crucial part is probably restarting the application, since looking at the espec code it seems that it tries to start the application in the beginning.

Comment: Although this is not related to your question, why espec instead of Elixir's ex_unit? Have you given ex_unit a serious try before falling back to other solutions?

Comment: Reloading The Application does not seem to work. I have not given ex_unit a try but I already implementing working specs in espec.

Comment: Apparently it's an espec problem: https://github.com/antonmi/espec/issues/43